# Multiprocessing program - Not Executing in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am currently scrapping data from various sites.
The code for the scrappers is stored in modules (x,y,z,a,b)

Where x.dump is a function which uses Files for storing the scraped data.
The dump function takes a single argument 'input'.
Note : All the dump functions are not same.

I am trying to run each of these dump function in parallel.
The following code runs fine.
But i have noticed that it still follows serial order x then y ... for execution.

Is this the correct way of going about the problem?

Are multithreading and multiprocessing the only native ways for parallel programming?

```
from multiprocessing import Process

import x.x as x
import y.y as y
import z.z as z
import a.a as a
import b.b as b

input = ""

f_list = [x.dump, y.dump, z.dump, a.dump, b.dump]
processes = []

for function in f_list:
        processes.append(Process(target=function, args=(input,)))

for process in processes:
        process.run()

for process in processes:
        process.join()
```

Comment: If you have many files to process, you may consider using a pool. You have a fixed number of workers (usually, the numer of CPU cores) and a queue of tasks that get consumed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because `run()` is the method to implement the task itself, you're not meant to call it from outside like that.  You are supposed to call `start()` which spawns a new process which then calls `run()` in the other process and returns control to you so you can do more work (and later `join()`).

Comment: Thank you.
That was exactly it.
Thank you for the answer
I will accept the answer ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

You should be calling process.start() not process.run()

The start method does the work of starting the extra process and then running the run method in that process.

[Python docs](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)